# Track NSManagedObject property when it was updated and immediately update view

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, key-value-observing, magicalrecord

I have a question how can I listen to changes in my data model.

I have NSManagedObject email with property progress. So while app is sending email, I every time update property progress.

I want to listen to data model and if changed update my view.

I added:

```
 for (SAPEmail *email in _emails)
    {
        [self addObserver:email forKeyPath:@"progress" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    }


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"progress"])
    {
        SAPEmail *email = object;

        NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>> progress: %@", email.progress);
    }
}
```

But seems it does not work for me.

I also using MagicalRecord.

I also tried to observe context

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
      addObserver:self 
         selector:@selector(handleDataModelChange:) 
             name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification 
           object:myManagedObjectContext];
```

But when I debug my data model already was being update 10 times (because I update progress from 0 - 9), but handleDataModelChange invoked just once after all update where made. But I need to get all 10 update each time when data model updated to update progress view.

One more if I use this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(managedObjectContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
```

and then for example try to refresh data:

```
- (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>+++++");

    _emails = [SAPCoreDataEmailHelper emailsWithStatus:EmailStatusInProgress];

    [_theTableView reloadData];
}

+ (NSArray *)emailsWithStatus:(EmailStatus)status
{
    NSPredicate *prediacte = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %d", status];
    NSArray *emails = [SAPEmail MR_findAllWithPredicate:prediacte];
    return emails;
}
```

I can see how works NSLog but then my app is freeze.

Answer (score 1):

Even better, hold your fetched objects in a `NSFetchedResultsController`. In this way you can automatically monitor very specific entities without going into too much detail for observing every attribute.

Have you controller implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods. It is really simple, check out the Xcode templates using Core Data (e.g. Master-Detail Project, check "Core Data").

Answer (score 0):

You're setting up the observer incorrectly, use the following code to set up your observations.

```
 for (SAPEmail *email in _emails)
 {
     [email addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"progress" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
 }
```

I also recommend [setting the context parameter](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2008/09/24/proper_kvo_usage/) for KVO observations to be triggered properly.

---

Update

When you want to observe changes from Core Data, you have some options. I don't think you are grasping that there are multiple ways to do it. The first way is to watch for changes to a single property on a single object. This is the KVO approach. If you want to listen to save events for a particular context, then you'll need to use the NSNotificationCenter approach. You'll need to mix the two when you're making changes to multiple contexts. That is, if you're observing a property on an object in context A, and you make changes to that object/property in context B, you need to set up the NSNotificationCenter observation handler on NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification to merge the new changes from context B into context A. From there, when the context merge is complete, then your KVO observation on property/object in context A is then triggered.

In your case, in your `managedOjbectContextDidSave:` method, you need to call 
`-mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` to merge your changes between contexts. I also recommend using multiple contexts, and not hold a single context in your SAPCoreDataEmailHelper class. When you get to multithreaded scenarios, you will encounter random crashes with a single context and multiple threads.

Comment: thank you for answer you every time help me) I have singleton that send email for me and here I using magical import to set all properties as well as progress. In another object in view controller I want to observe all of my emails and when I init this view controller I make SAPEmail MR_findAllWithPredicate. But I think when core data makes changes the emails I use in view controller don't know about it. Because changes happened in context not for objects I get via MR_findAllWithPredicate. Correct?

Comment: still can't observe it